# forum posts display loading slowly

Tags: php, mysql, performance, mysqli, forum

I am new to php coding and am coding a website (with forums) to learn.

Currently I have one dynamic page that handles all the forum aspects from displaying the topics, all the forums and then each post itself.

Each of these topics/forums and posts are held in mySQL and accessed when needed.

the first two sections (Display all topics and Display all forums) loads perfectly fine however when we get to the third section (Display all posts for the forum) the loading is very slow. My test page only has 16 posts and very little text however takes while to load.

I have paging so each page only holds 25 posts however it is slow at 16 with little text so hard to image 25 posts with loads of texts/images.

Thanks for any help and suggestions in advance :).

Here is a reduced code from the forums page (Only showing the necessary parts):

```
<?php
$topicID = $_GET['topicID'];
$forumID = $_GET['forumID'];
include_once '../includes/forumsData.php';

sec_session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
include_once 'header.php';
include_once 'navbar.php';
?>
        <div class="bg">        
            <!-- Body -->
            <div class='body'>
                <div class="forum-title">Forums</div>
<?php       
                // No topic chosen
                // Display all topics
                if(!isset($topicID)) {
                    for ($x = 0; $x < count($headers); $x++) {
                            echo '<div class="forum-header">' . $headers[$x][0] . '</div>';
                        for ($z = 0; $z < count($topics); $z++) {
                            if($topics[$z][6] == $headers[$x][1]) {
                                echo '<div class="forums">
                                        <div class="topics">
                                            <a href="?topicID=' . $topics[$z][7] . '">' . $topics[$z][0] . '</a></font>
                                            <br>
                                            ' . $topics[$z][1] . '
                                        </div>';
                                        if ($topics[$z][3] == ""){
                                            echo '<div class="info">No new Posts</div>';
                                        }
                                        else {
                                         echo '<div class="info"><a href = "../profile/?profile=' . $topics[$z][4] . '"><img src="../images/profileA/' . $topics[$z][2] . '" height="45" width="45" /></a><p><a href="?topicID=' . $topics[$z][7] . '&forumID=' . $topics[$z][8] . '">' . $topics[$z][3] . '</a><br><a href="../profile/?profile=' . $topics[$z][4] . '">' . $topics[$z][4] . '</a> - ' . get_date_diff($mysqli, $topics[$z][5]) . '</p></div>';
                                        }
                                    echo '</div>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Topic has been chosen
                // Display all the forum posts

                if(isset($topicID) && check_topic_exists($mysqli, $topicID) && empty($forumID)) {
                    echo '<br><a href="./">Forums</a> > <a href="./?topicID='. $topicID . '">' . get_topic_name($mysqli, $topicID) . '</a><br><br>

                    <a href="posting.php?topicID='. $topicID . '&mode=post">Create New Topic</a><br>';

                    echo '<div class="forum-topicHeader">Topic</div>
                        <div class="forum-repliesHeader">Replies</div>
                        <div class="forum-lpHeader">Latest post</div>';

                    if (count($forums) > 0) {
                        for ($x = 0; $x < count($forums); $x++) {
                            $replies = $forums[$x][6] -1;
                            echo '
                            <div class="forums">
                                <div class="topics">
                                    <a href="?topicID=' . $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forums[$x][0] . '">' . $forums[$x][2] . '</a><br><a href="../profile/?profile=' . $forums[$x][4] . '">' . $forums[$x][4] . '</a></td>
                                </div>
                                <div class="replies">
                                    ' . $replies . '
                                </div>
                                <div class="info">
                                    <a href="../profile/?profile=' . get_latest_user_reply($mysqli, $topicID, $forums[$x][0]) . '">' . get_latest_user_reply($mysqli, $topicID, $forums[$x][0]) . '</a><br> ' . get_date_diff($mysqli, $forums[$x][5]) . '
                                </div>
                            </div>';
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Topic has been chosen
                // Forum has been chosen
                // Display all posts for the forum

                if(isset($topicID) && check_topic_exists($mysqli, $topicID) && isset($forumID)) {
                    require '../BBCode/BBCodeParser.php';
                    $bbcode = new Golonka\BBCode\BBCodeParser;

                    echo '<br><a href="./">Forums</a> > <a href="./?topicID='. $topicID . '">' . get_topic_name($mysqli, $topicID) . '</a> > <a href="./?topicID='. $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forumID . '">' . get_forum_name($mysqli, $topicID, $forumID) . '</a>';
                    echo '<br><br>
                    <a href="posting.php?topicID='. $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forumID . '&mode=post">Post New Reply</a>
                    <div class="post-title ">' . get_forum_name($mysqli, $topicID, $forumID) . '</div><br>';
                    if (count($posts) > 0) {
                        for ($x = 0; $x < count($posts); $x++) {
                            echo '
                            <div class="post-header">' . $posts[$x][3] . '<text style="float:right">#' . ($x+1) . '</text></div>
                            <div class="post">
                                <div class="post-user ">';
                                if(login_check($mysqli) && (permission_check($mysqli) == 2 || permission_check($mysqli) == 3 || $username == $posts[$x][5])) {
                                    echo '<a href="posting.php?topicID='. $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forumID . '&postID=' . $posts[$x][1] . '&mode=edit">Edit</a><br>';
                                }
                                echo '<a href="../profile/?profile="' . $posts[$x][5] . '">' . $posts[$x][5] . '</a>
                                <br>
                                <a href="#">Add img here soon</a>
                                <br>
                                Other user infos?
                                </div>
                                <div class="post-text">' . $bbcode->parse($posts[$x][4]) . '</div>
                            </div><br>';
                        }
                    }
                    echo '<a href="posting.php?topicID='. $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forumID . '&mode=post">Post New Reply</a><br><br>';
                }

                // If we have selected a topic that doesn't exist
                if(!empty($topicID) && !check_topic_exists($mysqli, $topicID))
                {
                    include_once 'topicnotfound.php';
                }
?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Within the forumsData.php I access the database and put the data into arrays depending on the TopicID and forumID. e.g:

```
    $nquery = 'SELECT * FROM tableexample WHERE topicidcol = ' . $topicID . ' AND forumidcol = ' . $forumID;
    $ndata = mysqli_query($mysqli, $nquery);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ndata)) 
    {
        // insert date into array
        $myarray[$z] = array($row['datacol1'], $row['datacol2']);
        $z++
    }
```

Comment: mmm... what do you do every calls of the next functions: `check_topic_exists()`, `get_topic_name()`, `login_check()`, `permission_check()` and etc (all of them requires `$mysqli`) ? is that functions gets data directly from mysql everytime?

Comment: It doesn't resolve your problem, but is `ORDER BY WHERE topicidcol...` in your 2nd code block valid SQL or just a typo?

Comment: sure? .. mysql isn't so fast, for frequent requests (may be it's enough for this example due internal cache) .. but it's a bad idea, you need to set up flags (and any other data) before output.

Comment: @Wizard - those functions go into the DB and check certain things. e.g. checking the topic exists means if you manually typed ?topicID=# into the search bar it will display an error if the topic does not exist. Each of the functions should be self explanatory from their names. I used $mysqli in the params becasue when i learnt to do the function checks from a tutorial they used it and I just replicated it.

Comment: @PerlDog Just a typo, I renamed some of it to keep it easy to read.

Comment: every time, when you display post, you check user login and permissions, I think user can not be changed while you output list of posts, it's enough to check him once, before the loop, and use a variable inside the loop.

Comment: @Wizard I check the user permissions for post editing e.g. only admins/mods can edit a post and you can only edit your own post. How would this sort of check be done outside of a loop when it depends on the post being looked at in the array at the time?

Comment: $isLogged = login_check($mysqli); $hasPrivileges = (permission_check($mysqli) == 2 || permission_check($mysqli) == 3);
...
while (..) { 

if($isLogged && ($hasPrivleges || $username == $posts[$x][5])) {
                                    echo '<a href="posting.php?topicID='. $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forumID . '&postID=' . $posts[$x][1] . '&mode=edit">Edit</a><br>';
                                }
}

Comment: @Wizard That has improved the speed considerably. Thank you

Comment: @Matt https://github.com/thunderer/Shortcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question partially resolved by checking permissions once outside the loop, here is the part of code:

```
            // Topic has been chosen
            // Forum has been chosen
            // Display all posts for the forum

            if(isset($topicID) && check_topic_exists($mysqli, $topicID) && isset($forumID)) {
                require '../BBCode/BBCodeParser.php';
                $bbcode = new Golonka\BBCode\BBCodeParser;

                echo '<br><a href="./">Forums</a> > <a href="./?topicID='. $topicID . '">' . get_topic_name($mysqli, $topicID) . '</a> > <a href="./?topicID='. $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forumID . '">' . get_forum_name($mysqli, $topicID, $forumID) . '</a>';
                echo '<br><br>
                <a href="posting.php?topicID='. $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forumID . '&mode=post">Post New Reply</a>
                <div class="post-title ">' . get_forum_name($mysqli, $topicID, $forumID) . '</div><br>';
                if (count($posts) > 0) {


                    // checking user login & privileges
                    $isLogged = login_check($mysqli);
                    $hasPrivileges = (permission_check($mysqli) == 2 || permission_check($mysqli) == 3);


                    for ($x = 0; $x < count($posts); $x++) {
                        echo '
                        <div class="post-header">' . $posts[$x][3] . '<text style="float:right">#' . ($x+1) . '</text></div>
                        <div class="post">
                            <div class="post-user ">';

                            // changed condition, avoiding frequent mysql request
                            if($isLogged && ($hasPrivileges || $username == $posts[$x][5])) {


                                echo '<a href="posting.php?topicID='. $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forumID . '&postID=' . $posts[$x][1] . '&mode=edit">Edit</a><br>';
                            }
                            echo '<a href="../profile/?profile="' . $posts[$x][5] . '">' . $posts[$x][5] . '</a>
                            <br>
                            <a href="#">Add img here soon</a>
                            <br>
                            Other user infos?
                            </div>
                            <div class="post-text">' . $bbcode->parse($posts[$x][4]) . '</div>
                        </div><br>';
                    }
                }
                echo '<a href="posting.php?topicID='. $topicID . '&forumID=' . $forumID . '&mode=post">Post New Reply</a><br><br>';
            }
```

Comment: Loads almost instantly now; thank you. Will keep an eye out for any more functions inside loops in the rest of the website.

Comment: yep) ..if you wanna hold 5-6k connections at the same time - you need optimize every part of web-application, in the worst cases even caches like memcache / redis can't helps, but 95% of cases will significantly speedup with cache.

Comment: oh.. this `$hasPrivileges = (permission_check($mysqli) == 2 || permission_check($mysqli) == 3);` can be changed to `$hasPrivileges = in_array(permission_check($mysqli), array(2,3));`

Answer (score 0):

Use `microtime(true)` to get some timings.  Determine which of these is the problem:  (1) `SELECT` (`mysqli_query` call), (2) looping through the rows, (3) building the page, or (4) stuff elsewhere.

If it is the `SELECT`, then you possibly need this composite index (in either order):

```
INDEX(topicidcol, forumidcol)
```

Also, you should tack on and `ORDER BY` and a `LIMIT 25`, even if there are only 16 (since you don't know there are only 16).

25 rows should not be a problem.  The 100th page of 25 posts will be a problem, but you will come back later to ask why.